Placeholders wrongly replaced with % char
I want to change placeholder in a string, separated by % char. For example, %test% should be replaced by SERVER (in the example here). Others cases would be like %name% changed by the user name.
One of my problem is placeholders are not known before using it. So, we have to try for each placeholders to find if it's a valid one, or else keep the %.
Also, I can NOT know about the placeholders, and simply use a.replace("%test%", "SERVER"). I don't want to try to check if it's a right one because it could miss some, and/or have false positives.
Example of line:

abc %some%%test% efz %other% fref%
Some line with 1% of %some_placeholders%

My actual code:
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String base = "abc %some%%test% efz %other% fref%"; // here is my line

        String completeLine = ""; // the result
        String[] parts = base.split("\\%"); // split by separator
        for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) { // for each parts
            String param = parts[i];
            String placeholder = placeholder(param); // change placeholder
            completeLine += placeholder;
            if(placeholder.equals(param) && i > 0) { // if not placeholder and not first %
                completeLine += "%";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(completeLine);
    }
    
    private static String placeholder(String param) {
        if(param.equalsIgnoreCase("test"))
            return "SERVER";
        return param;
    }
}

Actual result:

abc some%%SERVER efz %other% fref%

Expected result:

abc %some%SERVER efz %other% fref%

Before, I was using this:
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String base = "abc %some%%test% efz %other% fref%";

        String completeLine = "";
        for (String param : line.split("\\%")) {
            completeLine += placeholder(param);
        }
        System.out.println(completeLine);
    }
    
    private static String placeholder(String param) {
        if(param.equalsIgnoreCase("test"))
            return "SERVER";
        return param;
    }
}

But all % were disappearing, so the result was: abc someSERVER efz other fref.
I also think about checking char-by-char but it's too long and very non-efficient.
As you can see, the placeholder is well replaced but some % are missing. I tried to change when I add a new % (instead of adding after completeLine += placeholder;, I do it before). But I already don't have the right expected output (% are wrongly placed).
How can I keep the % without checking char-by-char?

Regarding if(placeholder == param... please see How do I compare strings in Java?. Anyway consider requiring from provided data to always escape % with another %. So when you are looking for %non-percentage% and find %% the non-percentage is empty. In this case replace it with single %. Otherwise replace that placeholder with value corresponding to non-percentage.

Just had a thought.  How many placeholders do you have?  It may be simpler to just try and brute force replace them instead of finding those that exist in the string.  Of course lots of placeholders and/or very long strings would be repetitive and thus inefficient.

@WJS I can have infinite one. In reality, there is like %x_1_y% that will look in "x" database for first user in the "y" stats. So, at least I can know with a prefix like all starting by "x" could be a placeholders, but I can't know all of them

I'd take a different approach. For each placeholder that you need to replace (so that's presumably passed as an argument?), look for it in the string, and if found, replace it.

@Cerbrus I don't know all placeholders. The placeholder(String) method is an example of external placeholders check. I already to that for some regular  one that I know

There's got to be some point where you can identify the placeholder you need to replace...

FYI, this question is being discussed on meta: Why could it be that my java question about searching and replacing in string was badly received?

@Cerbrus  "There's got to be some point where you can identify the placeholder you need to replace"  I agree.  And that is done when the OP parses the string to grab the placeholders and then tries to substitute each via the placeholder method.  If there is a mapping, it replaces it.  If not, it in effect leaves it alone by replacing the placeholder with itself.

@WJS I'm thinking of the opposite approach. You get a (variable) list of input data, being placeholders and their replacement values. Iterate over that, and replace what you can. Replacing placeholder tokens with their plain text values is weird...

@Cerbrus OP mentions they are getting the variable values dynamically from the database ("In reality, there is like %x_1_y% that will look in "x" database for first user in the "y" stats") so that's probably not practical for them (Otherwise they'd have to fetch the entire table where they are getting these values from).

"The difficulty is others % that are not placeholders." Does it even make the whole problem ill posed and unsolvable? Example "%some%test%" what would the expected result be? Either you underspecified the problem and there are restrictions on how the other % are used or you likely will run into ambiguities at some point. Also, the question does not show any research.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution I made research before, to find the MRE. I don't explain that this code is not my first, and after some search I made this one. I just try to don't explain my life as it will not help to find an answer for a problem if I say I tried something else

This question is very similar to, and has the same solution(s) as ReplaceAll with java8 lambda functions

"I also think about checking char-by-char but it's too long and very non-efficient." — I'll agree with the verbosity argument, but not the inefficiency one.  Any solution to this problem is ultimately going to boil down to checking char-by-char.  There exist both efficient and inefficient ways of doing this.

What is the purpose of the "Some line with 1% of %some_placeholders%" line?  It doesn't seem to be referenced in the actual code or anywhere else?

@Elikill58 " I made research before..." Then show it. Or at the very least describe it. As I said, the question does not show the research.

@M.Justin it just to add some new examples as few people requested. For the reserched, I already edited my post few hours ago to add other code

@AbdulAzizBarkat "they are getting the variable values dynamically from the database" so, then you know the variables to replace...

This question is similar to: ReplaceAll with java8 lambda functions. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@yivi it's litterally explained on the post, the 3rd paragraph is for that..

Yes, I read the question. Including the third paragraph. You'll note the solutions in the suggested dupe are the same as the ones used to answer this question. That's what makes it a dupe. Thanks. Bye.

You could also do the following:
String base = "abc %some%%test% efz %other% fref%";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("%.*?%").matcher(base);
String completeLine= base;
while (m.find())  {
     completeLine = completeLine.replace(m.group(), placeholder(m.group()));
}
System.out.println(completeLine);

private static Map<String,String> map = Map.of("%test%", "SERVER", "%other%", "OTHER");
private static String placeholder(String param) {
    return map.getOrDefault(param, param);
}

prints
abc %some%SERVER efz OTHER fref%

The modification of the placeholder method is simply a suggestion on using a map to hold the placeholder to replacement mappings.  If no mapping is found the original placeholder is returned.

Yep. The solution follows the examples given. Format the strings incorrectly or ambiguously and you get different results.

This is still doable with replaceAll, just a different variation.
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\%([a-zA-Z]*)\\%");

String completeLine = pattern.matcher(base)
  .replaceAll(matchResult -> placeholder(matchResult.group(1)));


Hmm ... does this remove the %'s for %test% and not for %some% ?

It will remove the %'s for all occurrences, so also for %some%.

To fix that you would need a placeholder method that accepts both matchResult.group(1) (e.g. test) and matchResult.group() (e.g. %test%). Alternatively, use only matchResult.group() and include the %'s in the matching, like WJS' answer.

I like the simplicity of this, but note that implementor probably wants to wrap the placeholder call with Matcher.quoteReplacement. For example, this code does not work if placeholder returns any string containing \ or $ which isn't followed by 1, and so on Windows it fails for OS paths. eg try Path.of("/").toString()
